# Single key printing for each value

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, printing, key-value

I am using python to run a for loop to print out every value in a specific URL, but each value is printing to a new dictionary with the same key instead of inserting multiple values into one dictionary.

How can I get the all the values for a specific key to be inserted into a single unique key?

```
kernelLinks = []

for values in output:
  links = links + ([("https://www.kaggle.com" + (values["scriptUrl"]))])

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
method = {}
dictionary = []

for url in links: 
    driver.get(url)
    driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    data = driver.page_source
    data2 = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

    for a in data2.find_all('span', class_="n"):
        data2 = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
        dictionary = {}
        kernel = url
        method = a.text
        dictionary[kernel] = method
        print(dictionary)
```

current output:

{'https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/data-sciencetutorial-for-beginners': 'check_output'}
{'https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/data-sciencetutorial-for-beginners': 'data'}
{'https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/data-sciencetutorial-for-beginners': 'decode'}
.....

desired output:

{'https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/data-sciencetutorial-for-beginners': 'check_output', 'data', 'decode}

Comment: What is `dictionary1`? Where is `url` defined? It looks like `url` is coming from the previous `for` loop which has already run to completion so you'll just get the last value of `url`. Or, is the second `for` loop actually indented to be inside the first?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read up on how to create a [mcve]. Most of your code is unrelated to the essence of your problem. Try to write a little bit of code to test your understanding of loops, as you recreate a new dictionary every time through. Also, have a look at [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Please provide a bit more context about your variables, and also the desired output?

Comment: My apologies all, I have updated the question. I am trying to change the current key (kaggle url) to a unique that contains all the values that are currently being printed separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the relevant part of your question is:

> How can I get the all the values for a specific key to be inserted into a single unique key?

You may want to use another data-structure to hold the different values.
For example a *set* if you're only interested what different values there are, but not in duplicates. (If you want to keep track all the values, switch to a *list* and use *append* instead of *add*.) This answer demonstrates how you could keep track of css classes assigned to different html elements on a page you want to parse. It assumes you somehow already obtained the elements and their classes.

```
items = [
    ('span', 'pretty'),
    ('div', 'listing'),
    ('div', 'header'),
    ('span', 'ugly'),
    ('div', 'footer'),
]

data = dict()
for elem, css_class in items:
    classes = data.setdefault(elem, set())
    classes.add(css_class)
    
print data
```